# Python C_API: how to define nested classes?

Tags: python, class, nested, c-api

I'm currently writing a C extension module for python using the "raw" C-API. I would like to be able to define "nested classes" like in the following python code

```
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.i = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = A.B()
a = A()
b = A.B()
print(a.b.i)
print(b.i)
```

How can I create with the C-API a nested class like A.B?

Comment: Define the `B` type first, then just make it an attribute of the `A` type.

Comment: I don't know about the C API, but in Python itself there is almost never a good reason to create nested classes. Python is not Java.

Comment: What code do you use to define a class?